# Saddles and Bent Metal Rails

Tags: parts, saddle

Has anyone else had issues with bent (slow deformation over time) metal rails on the saddles they have used? I previously had three or four saddles that all ended up tilted over to one side and accordingly less comfortable than when they were new.  I have since switched to only carbon railed saddles and have not had any issues.  However, I am now wondering if it might have been a brand issue (I can't recall if the set of saddles in question was all from one manufacturer or not, but it's a possibility) or this has occurred with other riders.

The head mechanic at my shop claimed it was "just me" and I do have an ugly stroke, but I am wondering if others out there have experienced this or if I should have been blaming the manufacturer.

Comment: Being a featherweight, this is one issue I've never had...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not just had them bend I have had them fracture. 
I took my saddle to the shop thinking they would say "wow how did that happen" and the response I got was it happens all the time - that saddle is a few years old. 
Aluminum will fatigue - low end seats have a limited life. 
A steel or titanium seat does not suffer from fatigue (will not at nearly the level of aluminum). 
Carbon also is reported not to fatigue but I don't have any experience with carbon railed saddles. 
Inspect your rails on a regular basis for deformation or cracks. 
If you go out the back and land your bumm on the wheel because the rail fractured it gets a lot easier to spend $100 on a saddle.

I think the seat position was also a factor as I had the seat all the way back.  What that does is create a longer lever from the back of seat to where the rail is clamped.  I also put an offset seat post on the bike so I got what I consider a better clamp position.

[image: BrokenSaddle]

Comment: Wow, that looks like it would have been disturbing.  The rails in question were mostly Ti.  I think I prefer the bending to the aluminum snap for less disturbing mental imagery.

Comment: I've not experienced this. When yours broke, did you "feel" anything or was it just....snap? i.e. anything you can look back at and describe as a symptom?

Comment: @PeteH At the time I was not even aware my seat failed.  I went no hands and just went out the back.  A month later when I was ready to ride again I discovered the fracture. Part of the crack had rust/dirt (was old) so if I had inspected I could have prevented.

Comment: Nice, looks just the same as mine last year. @PeteH: I didn't have an accident as it broke, so I can tell a bit more: I didn't really feel when it broke, just noticed that the saddle seemed to be bit more "wobbly" when riding. The good thing was, that under load the ends of the broken bar were pressed against each other which kept the whole thing somewhat stable and was enough to get me home.

Answer (score 1):

I have had Ti rails break on me on a particular seat brand that i no longer use. I am a heavy mountain bike users:  lots of climbs, jumps, and DH. Its not just you. I suggest the seats with Cromo rails. So far I have never had any WTB saddles break on me that have cromo rails for example. Forget the TI and Aluminum, Cromo is also better for riders 200 lbs+ and the weight increase is minimal in such small rails! You can most certainly blame the manufacturer on that one IMO.

Comment: Thanks.  My rails don't need to be that "sturdy" as my riding is mostly road or cross country.  I'm also only in the 170 to 185lb category, so I shouldn't be stressing them that much.  I tend to be weight weenie where ever I can since every little bit helps me float on snow.