# Is rotating seat post 180 degrees to get a tri position a good idea?

Tags: road-bike, triathlon

So I'm in the process of converting my road bike to a tri bike as much as possible. I would like to push the seat saddle a little more. So I rotated the post and adjusted the saddle as in the picture below. However I worried that such position might make it prone to snap to I reverted the change.
Picture of post with adjusted saddle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsIt9.jpg

Comment: Do it carefully, and inspect any saddle moves before big rides. The notch ends on the post are pretty soft and delicate.

Comment: You should be fine with a rotated saddle, but if it feels off to you, don't do it!

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm going to refrain from doing that because although the seat post is carbon I feel that it going to snap on bumpy rides. I will purchase a seatpost that has an angle

Answer (score 2):

I ride my bikes HARD (BMX park/street/dirt) and back in the 90s we had to use what ever parts we could find. Since no one was making parts back then for BMX, it was usually MTB parts. Even back then and with all the abuse we put them through, (yes, even flipping seats and posts backwards to fit our needs) the parts seemed to hold up pretty well (Except the hollow axles used for quick release, those snapped pretty easy), about the only thing was the posts would kink, but that was because they were raised way high and dropped from 30-40 feet up off the ground. I can't tell what brand of post that it, but it looks more solid than the crap we used back then, and we beat them up pretty good. My guess is that you will be fine.

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25737/saddles-and-bent-metal-rails/25738#25738  And I was not riding hard

Comment: good point, we did not use seats with aluminum rails, they were all steel/cro-mo, but they bent like crazy, sometimes poking up through the plastic. Eventually companies like Primo started making seats with stronger rails, and now they drop them so low they are little more than seat-tube covers...

Answer (score 1):

Rotating the post should not be a problem

On the saddle there is a range on the rails that you may be past
Often the range will be marked

I had a rail break but I was too far back

Avoid aluminum rails as aluminum fatigues