# Is it possible to replace the seat rails on a saddle?

Tags: saddle

My saddle's rails have become bent so that the saddle is askew. Rather than get a new saddle, is there any way to replace just the rails?

I assume bending them back is useless, as even if i could get them totally straight they would be weakened and just bend again.

Comment: Saddles are not something to cheap if you want to reproduce.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25737/saddles-and-bent-metal-rails/25738#25738

Comment: Saddles are parts like tyres and drive-trains that wear out and need replacing from time to time.

Comment: I've tried - its generally not possible unless you have a high-end saddle that is not a lightweight racing one.   Bending the rails back is a recipe for future failure - you can exert a lot of force on your saddle, and  bending will weaken it.

Comment: **how** did you bend your bike saddle's rails?  Was there a crash or was it damaged in storage ?

Comment: By being 18 stone. I'm not sure exactly when it happened, maybe I went over a bump

Answer (score 7):

High end saddles like Brooks do offer rail and frame replacements: http://www.brooksengland.com/en_us/spare-parts.html

You might google "yoursaddlecompany rail replacement"

But if your saddle cost less than US$50,
I doubt it is economic to do so. Stocking SKUs and supporting a repair/parts department costs money for the saddle company.

You're better off either just getting a new saddle or seeing if you can't buy a used saddle with a trashed seat cover and doing a transplant. Note that many saddles are riveted on so this may be a big pain.

Answer (score 1):

In this video Jan replacing the rails using improvised clamps of plates and bolts and bends rails inside to remove them from the saddle. He also uses levers to achieve high momentum.